# aggregate function return correct value after a while

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When I run the below for loop, month increment every for steps and give in `getUserNumberAndPaymentsbyMonth` function as a below:

**EDIT**

```
for(var i = 1; i<= getCurrentMonth; i++){
    console.log("getting month ", i)
    var userNum = await getUserNumberAndPaymentsbyMonth(companyName, i).then((data)=>{
        getUserCountperMount.push(data[1])
        }
        ).catch(console.error);
   }
```

But sometimes getUserNumberAndPaymentsbyMonth returns "0" so I debug this function.
And this function as in below:

**EDIT:**

```
async function getUserNumberAndPaymentsbyMonth(operatorName, month) {
  // const operator = await Operators.findOne({operatorName});
  // var myDate = new Date(2022, 7, 19);
  console.log(month);

  var totalPaymentsPerMouth = 0;
  var totalUserNumberPerMount = 0;
  var value = await Operators.aggregate(
    [
      { $unwind: "$users" },
      { $match: { operatorName: operatorName } },
      {
        $project: {
          month: { $month: "$users.paymentsData" },
          operatorName: 1,
          users: "$users"
        }
      },
      {
        $match: {
          // 'users.paymentsData': { "$gte": new Date("2022-07-24"), "$lt": new Date("2022-07-27")},
          month: {
            $eq: month
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    function (err, docs) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("db getting errror");
        console.log(err);
        // return [0,0];
      } else {
        docs.forEach(function (data) {
          totalUserNumberPerMount = totalUserNumberPerMount + 1;
          totalPaymentsPerMouth = totalPaymentsPerMouth + data.users.payment;
        });
        console.log("getIn");
        console.log(totalPaymentsPerMouth);
        console.log(totalUserNumberPerMount);
      }
    }
  );
  console.log("output: ", totalPaymentsPerMouth, totalUserNumberPerMount);

  return [totalPaymentsPerMouth, totalUserNumberPerMount];
}
```

When I debug this function, when I get the false value, after a bit time later I get correct value below `getIn` console output. but it's too late for me to get this value because it's out of the for loop. How cna I write the code properly. Where is my fault.

I want that a value is not returned in the getUserNumberAndPaymentsbyMonth function until the aggregate query is completed. If there is an error in the query, I can catch it in the error section, but this query should not exit before the end of the function.

I get this output:

```
getting month  1
1
getIn
0
0
output:  0 0
getting month  2
2
getIn
0
0
output:  0 0
getting month  3
3
output:  0 0
getting month  4
4
getIn
0
0
getIn
0
0
output:  0 0
getting month  5
5
getIn
0
0
output:  0 0
getting month  6
6
getIn
0
0
output:  0 0
getting month  7
7
output:  0 0
In function last:  [
  0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0
]
[
  0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0
]
**getIn. // correct value return after loop, getIn log working after a while.
1395
136**
```

Comment: `await Operators.aggregate` returns the aggregate result as an array. You can write your statement as `const docs = await Operators.aggregate`, and put this in a `try-catch` block.

Comment: Should I do like this  ; try{const docs = await Operators.aggregate..} catcht {} please give me more detail how cna I do that ? I want that a value is not returned in the getUserNumberAndPaymentsbyMonth function until the aggregate query is completed. If there is an error in the query, I can catch it in the error section, but this query should not exit before the end of the function.

Comment: You can use async-await syntax within the function `getUserNumberAndPaymentsbyMonth`. But, you are using a callback with await, and using `then`.

Comment: I edited my post but it does not work again, I get correct value after a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see you are providing a callback to your aggregate function which would execute for the result of aggregate query.

But as you need the output to be returned by your getUserNumberAndPaymentsbyMonth() function you don't need to put callback function there just rewrite your function like this

```js
async function getUserNumberAndPaymentsbyMonth(operatorName, month) {
  // const operator = await Operators.findOne({operatorName});
  // var myDate = new Date(2022, 7, 19);
  console.log(month);

  var totalPaymentsPerMouth = 0;
  var totalUserNumberPerMount = 0;
  var docs = await Operators.aggregate(
    [
      { $unwind: "$users" },
      { $match: { operatorName: operatorName } },
      {
        $project: {
          month: { $month: "$users.paymentsData" },
          operatorName: 1,
          users: "$users"
        }
      },
      {
        $match: {
          // 'users.paymentsData': { "$gte": new Date("2022-07-24"), "$lt": new Date("2022-07-27")},
          month: {
            $eq: month
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  ).toArray();
  
  //check for valid errors
  if (!docs) {
    console.log("db getting errror");
    console.log(err);
    // return [0,0];
  } else {
    docs.forEach(function (data) {
      totalUserNumberPerMount = totalUserNumberPerMount + 1;
      totalPaymentsPerMouth = totalPaymentsPerMouth + data.users.payment;
    });
    console.log("getIn");
    console.log(totalPaymentsPerMouth);
    console.log(totalUserNumberPerMount);
    return [totalPaymentsPerMouth, totalUserNumberPerMount];

  }
}
```

Comment: Thank yo for your answer but I get TypeError: Operators.aggregate(...).toArray is not a function. Can I remove .toArray ?

Comment: yeah try it . Being a developer never be afraid of trying .

Comment: I learned something new and solved my problem thanks to you.